# While deploying to heroku , I am getting the following error log

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku

I have used Postgresql add-on and NodeJS framework.In .gitignore file , I have already added npm-debug.log.

```
 2016-09-07T23:35:01.785651+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     node server.js
    2016-09-07T23:35:01.785817+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get their info via:
    2016-09-07T23:35:01.785982+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls version3
    2016-09-07T23:35:01.789051+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2016-09-07T23:35:01.789307+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
    2016-09-07T23:35:01.789464+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
    2016-09-07T23:35:01.888595+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
    2016-09-07T23:35:01.878834+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have all dependencies listed in your `package.json` file?
To add a library to package.json,

```
npm install<libName> --save
```

Comment: Hey , hi I added the code for more verbose error logging( used it from somewhere). Cookie-parser was not installed and thus was showing error.Thanks for the answer though